# Is there a filter which can convert light from the sun to Microwaves directly?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, climate-science

Is there a way to filter light from the sun (visible, UV, and/or IR) and convert the energy from it directly into Microwaves without putting in any energy? Barring this is there a way to do the same but while putting in a small amount of energy?

I was thinking if we could convert light from the sun into microwaves and blast them out of the atmosphere, then that seems like a novel way of combatting global warming by sapping energy out of the system which might otherwise reflect back off greenhouse gasses in the atmosphere. Feel free to school me if I’m wrong here.

Comment: The trouble with your idea is that it would take massive screens to capture and filter the sun.     A much easier way is to just get a few volcanoes to erupt and shoot all that dust into the upper atmosphere. It would block lots of sunlight.

Comment: Why not just a mirror?  If there are clouds, you're not getting much direct visible in the first place.  The mirror prevents much from being turned into IR.

Comment: @BowlOfRed if you were to use a mirror then for it to not just reflect back off greenhouse gases you would have to launch it into orbit around the planet, which would be terribly expensive and difficult, whereas microwaves can be shot from the ground and they’ll pass right through the atmosphere.

Comment: @foolishmuse but then you’d have to deal with the air pollution over large swaths of the planet, not to mention it would be much more difficult to control the amount it would actually block which could reek havoc on the amount of light plants actually need to survive, also that would have to be a massive volcano, and it would only be a temporary solution.

Comment: @Ethan, greenhouse gases efficiently block IR, not visible.  Most of what you're getting on the ground isn't IR.   Directly reflecting the visible is probably more efficient than some microwave conversion.

Comment: @Ethan  Now you understand why it's such a big problem.  Take a loo at this https://www.vice.com/en/article/ezpv7n/the-dark-ages-were-caused-by-two-enormous-volcanic-eruptions

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can find a material which has electrons that absorbs energy of UV, IR or visible light and then emits microwaves. Microwaves are merely the resonance frequencies of molecular vibrations (that's why its application increases temperature of water), while UV, visible light and IR are merely the resonance frequencies of the electrons, changing their energy state/orbital.

However, it would only work on the area which it covers to "blast energy to space". Therefore, you would have to cover quite a big portion of the atmosphere with it. Building that would probably be a bit too energy consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea except why throw away the down-converted microwave energy out to space when it might instead be beamed down to receivers on earth to generate electric power?

MSN picked up this relevant story from CNN titled "This wild, futuristic space plan could help save the world. But some say it’s too far-fetched
Story by By Laura Paddison, CNN • Dec. 27, 2023"

posted online at

https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/this-wild-futuristic-space-plan-could-help-save-the-world-but-some-say-it-s-too-far-fetched/ar-AA1m5Jcm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rectennas are used for the transmission of microwave power. If you could optically downconvert to microwave frequencies, then the rectenna would be the first step in extracting power directly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectenna